# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [invalid opcode: opcode 0x29 not defined]

Tags: solidity, javascript, etherscan, revert-opcode, invalid-opcode

hello every one hope you are doing fine.

i was trying to communicate with my smart contract which is deployed on the goeril test network but i m facing this error

**Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [invalid opcode: opcode 0x29 not defined]**

you can also see this issue on this link https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x462ada46bd7b38bbd835a4ee18f41a1e03e6fc8641feb7bf3dff0099d0895519

below is my javascript code to interact with smart contract.

```
function createAccount(){
web3.eth.defaultAccount = ACCOUNT_ADDRESS;

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.defaultAccount, function (err, nonce) {
    console.log("nonce value is "+ nonce);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address, {from: web3.eth.defaultAccount,gas: 3000000})
    const functionAbi = contract.methods.getBalance().encodeABI();
    var details = {
        "nonce": nonce,
        "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('47', 'gwei')),
        "gas": 300000,
        "to": address,
        "value": 0,
        "data": functionAbi,
    };
    const transaction = new EthereumTx(details, { chain: 'goerli' });
    transaction.sign(Buffer.from("8ccaa6aafdeecb5c01b07a4d9194b5b959df9fbdb9e2e57ba28c91c0bba4af18", 'hex'))
    var rawData = '0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawData)
        .on('transactionHash', function (hash) {
            console.log(['transferToStaging Trx Hash:' + hash]);
        
        })
        .on('receipt', function (receipt) {
            console.log(['transferToStaging Receipt:', receipt]);
        })
        .on('error', console.error);
});}
```

my solidity code file 1

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0


pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


import "./User.sol";

contract CryptoOp is User{

    constructor(){
        smart_contract_owner = msg.sender;
    }    

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function addFund() public isNotExists isValueSufficient payable returns(string memory){
        dataset[msg.sender].owner_balance += msg.value;
        return "Amount deposit successfully";
    }

    function sendFund(address payable receiver, uint _value) public isNotReceiver payable{
        require(dataset[msg.sender].owner_balance >= _value, "You have insufficient balance");
        (bool sent,) = receiver.call{value: _value}("");
        require(sent,"Failed to send");
        dataset[msg.sender].owner_balance-=_value;
        dataset[receiver].owner_balance+=_value;
    }

    function getMyBalance() public view isNotExists returns(uint){
        return dataset[msg.sender].owner_balance;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        dataset[msg.sender].owner_balance += msg.value;
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        dataset[msg.sender].owner_balance += msg.value;
    }

    

}
```

my solidity code file 2

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0


pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract User {

    address public smart_contract_owner;

    mapping(address => UserDeatils) public dataset;

    struct UserDeatils{
        string owner_name;
        address owner_address;
        uint owner_balance;
        uint owner_isExists;
        uint creation_date;
    }

    function createAccount(string memory name) public isUserAlreadyExists returns(string memory){
        UserDeatils memory userDeatils =  UserDeatils(name, msg.sender, 0, 1, block.timestamp);
        dataset[msg.sender] = userDeatils;
        return "User created successfully";
    }


    modifier isUserAlreadyExists {
        require(dataset[msg.sender].owner_isExists == 0, "User already exists");
        _;
    }

    modifier isNotExists {
        require(dataset[msg.sender].owner_isExists == 1, "User not exists");
        _;
    }

    modifier isNotReceiver {
        require(dataset[msg.sender].owner_isExists == 1, "Receiver not exists");
        _;
    }

    modifier isValueSufficient {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Need to send more than 0 ether");
        _;
    }
}
```

Comment: could be an issue with the contract itself, would be helpful to see the code of your contract in addition to your javascript.

Comment: @timsntech hi i just update my question i add the solidity code also thank you for replying and help me

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the goerli transactions that you are making a call to `0x00`, and not to an existing contract.

I guess the problem is `"to": address,` is undefined or `0x00`. Try copying the correct address and see if anything changes.